# leaflet l.control and marker overlap

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet l.control info popup on the top right corner of my map.

When I move one of my custom marker to the top right behind the l.control and release the mouse button, I am no more able to select the marker (because the l.control div is in the foreground)

Is there a way to prevent the user from dragging a marker behind the l.control div ?

I can't move the map to make the marker visible again as I plan to fix the marker position based on the container position (so if you move the map the marker will stay at the same place)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way to  disable marker draggable, when the mouse enter the div info.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: yeah i know, but my reputation is low to send comment. sorry guy

Answer (score 0):

If your final goal is to fix the marker position to the map's center, just don't make it draggable and use `L.Map`'s `move` event to update the marker when the map gets moved?

```
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    'center': [52.378333, 4.9],
    'zoom': 12,
    'layers': [
        L.tileLayer('//{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
        })
    ]
});

var marker = new L.Marker(map.getCenter()).addTo(map);

map.on('move', function () {
    marker.setLatLng(this.getCenter());
});
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PnnuMowCXvjRxyPqEj31?p=preview